# How can I report any regexp which never matched in the whole script?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, awk, sed

I often loop over lines in a file and apply several regexp substitutions, where I sometimes make mistakes so that one of these expressions never matches on any line. 
How can I find out which regexp didn't match without cluttering my code with checks? Does any scripting language provide metaprogramming facilities or debugging facilities for that?
Example input:

```
 foo
 bar
 baz
```

Example script (pseudocode):

```
 for each line of the file:
  s/foo/lorem/
  s/bazzz/ipsum/    # this never matches on any line and should get reported
```

**Edit:** I prefer Mark Thomas' solution, because I want the file to be read line by line and stops applying substitutions after the first match. Next time I should make my requirements clearer. A metaprogramming solution would have additional benefits, because I often do more complex case-specific processing line by line, although I think given the inspirations from the answers I can probably come up with a ruby extension method myself so that I can replace `gsub!` with `gsub_debug!` for debugging and get a report of all non-matching regular expressions when the program finished running.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirement to stop processing a line after the first successful replacement (from comment below)? Do you mean you want exactly/at most one replacement per line?

Comment: I took "_without cluttering my code with checks_" to the heart -- I don't think you can add some magical switch to the ready code, without adding checks. On a new project though, you can write a class to wrap regex and have it count matches by each pattern.  Thinking about it, such a module may well exist. (I found that [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/~rsavage/Regexp-Assemble-0.38/lib/Regexp/Assemble.pm) has the option `track` but couldn't get it to work.)

Comment: I haven't looked into Regexp::Assemble, but here's such a wrapper I came up with: https://gist.github.com/rubystallion/a28cb275f3209478253939decf9c2e31#file-regexpwrapper-pl  I'm still convinced that it should be possible to extend the existing substitution mechanism without adding checks or wrapping expressions, maybe not in perl, but surely in ruby, python or perl6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Ruby script that:

- Reads the substitutions from a simple delimited file
- Reads the file to process from the command line
- Stops applying substitutions to a line once one matches
- Reports which patterns did not match

Currently, it prints the output but it can be changed to write to a file.

**substitutions.txt**

```
foo     lorem
bazzz   ipsum
qux     notfound
```

**example.txt**

```
The foo and bazzz
The foo
The bazzz
and the ugly
```

**subs.rb**, invocation: `ruby subs.rb example.txt`

```
filename = ARGV[0]
substitutions = File.readlines("substitutions.txt").map(&:split)
used = {}

IO.foreach(filename) do |line|
    substitutions.each do |pattern, replacement|
        if line.gsub!(pattern, replacement)
            used[pattern] = true
            break #no more substitutions for this line
        end
    end
    puts line
end

unused = substitutions.map(&:first) - used.keys
unless unused.empty?
    puts "Unused patterns:"
    puts unused
end
```

Output:

```
The lorem and bazzz
The lorem
The ipsum
and the ugly

Unused patterns:
qux
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, [`gsub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) modifies the string in place and returns `nil` if the pattern hasn't been found:

```
text = "foo
bar
baz"

replacements = [['foo', 'lorem'], ['bazzz', 'ipsum']]
# or with regexen:
replacements = [[/foo/, 'lorem'], [/bazzz/, 'ipsum']]


replacements.each do |pattern, replacement|
  unless text.gsub!(pattern, replacement)
    puts "#WARNING: #{pattern} wasn't found"
  end
end

puts text
```

It outputs:

```
WARNING: bazzz wasn't found
lorem
bar
baz
```

Note that applying replacements one after the other can lead to bugs.

Comment: Replacing on the whole file is a good solution for me, because it's a small file and in my case the replacements are not likely to lead to bugs. I'll wait a bit longer if someone can come up with a solution that doesn't require keeping the entire file in memory and would also work if I didn't apply the replacements one after the other, but stopped processing a line after the first successful replacement. Thanks!

Comment: If the pattern is a regex rather than a string, use a Regex literal (`[/foo/, 'lorem']` or `[ %r{foo}, 'lorem']`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not really metaprogramming, but here's a Perl version which counts how many lines each pattern matches.  It doesn't modify the input data or the patterns and only keeps one line of input in memory at a time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @patterns = qw( foo bazzz );
my %matches;

for my $line (<DATA>) {
  for my $pat (@patterns) {
    if ($line =~ /$pat/) {
      $matches{$pat}++;
    }
  }
} 

for my $pat (sort @patterns) {
  say "$pat matched no lines" unless $matches{$pat};
} 

__DATA__
foo
bar
baz
```

Output:

```
bazzz matched no lines
```

**Edit:** How careless of me.  You want to do substitutions, not matches! That actually makes it a little simpler, since the Perl regex substitution operator returns the number of substitutions performed.  Here's a modified version which does that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %patterns = ( foo => 'lorem', bazzz => 'ipsum' );
my %matches;

for my $line (<DATA>) {
  for my $from (keys %patterns) {
    my $to = $patterns{$from};
    $matches{$from} += $line =~ s/$from/$to/g;
  }
} 

for my $pat (sort keys %patterns) {
  say "$pat matched no lines" unless $matches{$pat};
} 

__DATA__
foo
bar
baz
```

#### output

```
bazzz matched no lines
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    map["foo"] = "lorem"
    map["bazzz"] = "ipsum"
}
{
    for (re in map) {
        cnt[re] += gsub(re,map[re])
    }
    print
}
END {
    for (re in map) {
        print re, cnt[re]+0 | "cat>&2"
    }
}
' file
```

The above will print to stderr you how many times each substitution was made - massage to suit, e.g.:

```
END {
    for (re in map) {
        if ( cnt[re] == 0 ) {
            print "WARNING: never matched", re | "cat>&2"
        }
    }
}
```

It only keeps one line of the file at a time in memory.